# Does Autofac support look-up method injection?

Tags: autofac

There is a feature in Spring.Net called "look-up method injection", that allows the container to override the method. For example:
The method:

```
protected abstract DbConnection GetCurrentConnection();
```

The config file:

```
<lookup-method name="GetCurrentConnection" ref="connection"/>
```

Does Autofac support this feature? If not, is there any alternative approach?
I've considered two approaches, but allow of them seems anti-pattern

1. Use ServiceLocator
2. Inject a Func object

Comment: Could you explain better how the Spring lookup feature works? Some of us knows Autofac well, but not necessarily Spring ;-)

Comment: @PeterLillevold, thank you for replying. For more details about method injection in spring, pls visit [here](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-method-injection-lookup)

Comment: please include a short description in your question. A rule of thumb on SO: do not demand users do extra work in order to help you.

Comment: I followed the link, but I don't get it. It's still unclear to me what look-up method injection is. Please update your question and explain what you are actually trying to achieve.